# Can there be a position in which a player blocks check with checkmate?

Tags: problems, checkmate, check

Let's say that the first player gives a check to the second. player. Then the second player blocks and gives a checkmate. Is it possible?

Comment: And now explain why I am downvoted. I'll wait.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but maybe your original questions wasn't clear?

Comment: The original question was just as clear

Comment: I think you were downvoted because it is kind of a stupid question. There is no reason why this would be illegal or impossible.

Comment: It's better to be stupid for 5 minutes than to remain stupid for the entire life.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, here is an example:

```
[FEN "K4nqk/6q1/8/8/6P1/6Q1/8/8 w - - 0 1"]

1. Qh3+ Nh7#
```

Comment: Checkmate is the only truly forcing move!